# How to grep for specific pattern in a file

Tags: linux, shell, awk, grep

I have a bash file that has below line along with other lines.

```
var BUILD_VERSION       = '2014.17.10_23';
```

I just want to extract `2014.17.10_23`  and this value may change so something like grep for `2014*` . However when I do that I get the whole line returned instead of the value `2014.17.10_23`.

What would be the best way to achieve this?

Thanks

Comment: grep won't do this, you need awk or sed

Comment: Your regex effectively looks for `201`; you want something like `grep -oP "^var[ ]*BUILD_VERSION[ ]*=[ ]*'\K[^']*"`

Comment: @tripleee You should post that as an answer. It's a great solution and will be a good reference for others. You'll have my up-vote for it. `:)`

Comment: @Jaypal You will find hundreds, if not thousands, of duplicates for this question.  Please nominate to close as a duplicate instead of posting repetitive trivial answers.  If you find a better dupicate, please link to it.  If you find that the designated duplicate lacks a particular variant of the standard answers, feel free to add it there.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using `awk`:

```
awk -F= '/BUILD_VERSION/{print $2}' input | tr -d "[' ;]"
```

And with `sed`:

```
sed -n "/BUILD_VERSION/s/.*'\([^']*\)'.*/\1/p" input
```

Comment: This command works awk -F= '/BUILD_VERSION/{print $2}' input | tr -d "[' ;]"    The values in the souce file i am getting from below command    unzip -c work/$todeployname/warfile.war app/config/Property.js > /app/deployments/svnbuild.tmp . So instead of writing to a tmp file how can I directly feed that output of unizp - c to this command to get the build number  awk -F= '/BUILD_VERSION/{print $2}' input | tr -d "[' ;]"

Answer (score 1):

```
grep 'BUILD_VERSION' <your file> | sed -e 's/var BUILD_VERSION = //g'
```

Would get you `'2014.17.10_23';` tweak the sed expression (or pipe it through a few more) to get rid of quotes.

It would be a 1 liner regex in Perl...

Comment: This command works awk -F= '/BUILD_VERSION/{print $2}' input | tr -d "[' ;]" The values in the souce file i am getting from below command unzip -c work/$todeployname/warfile.war app/config/Property.js > /app/deployments/svnbuild.tmp . So instead of writing to a tmp file how can I directly feed that output of unizp - c to this command to get the build number awk -F= '/BUILD_VERSION/{print $2}' input | tr -d "[' ;]" –

Answer (score 1):

Here is another `awk` solution:

```
awk -F' = ' '/BUILD_VERSION/ {gsub(/\x27|;/,""); print $NF}'
```

Comment: This command works awk -F= '/BUILD_VERSION/{print $2}' input | tr -d "[' ;]" The values in the souce file i am getting from below command unzip -c work/$todeployname/warfile.war app/config/Property.js > /app/deployments/svnbuild.tmp . So instead of writing to a tmp file how can I directly feed that output of unizp - c to this command to get the build number awk -F= '/BUILD_VERSION/{print $2}' input | tr -d "[' ;]" –

Comment: @user1432622 pipe the output `your_command | awk ...`

Comment: Yes but how do I refer the filename from your_command after the pipe in awk command?

Answer (score 0):

You can use this `awk`

```
awk -F\' '/BUILD_VERSION/ {print $2}' file
2014.17.10_23
```

Comment: This command works awk -F= '/BUILD_VERSION/{print $2}' input | tr -d "[' ;]" The values in the souce file i am getting from below command unzip -c work/$todeployname/warfile.war app/config/Property.js > /app/deployments/svnbuild.tmp . So instead of writing to a tmp file how can I directly feed that output of unizp - c to this command to get the build number awk -F= '/BUILD_VERSION/{print $2}' input | tr -d "[' ;]" –

Comment: @user1432622 I am not familiar with how to get data from unzip. But you can remove the  `tr` command. `awk -F= '/BUILD_VERSION/ {gsub(/[; \x27]/,"",$2);print $2}' input`  The `\x27` creates the single quote `'`